# How to avoid text contour on an Android Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've tried and tried to draw a text with Canvas.drawText(...) and the
text shows up with correct foreground color (black), but there is also
a white contour around the letters. Couldn't get rid of the white contour.
I'd like just to see the black color, and the gray background between
the letters.
Do you know how this could be done, programmatically?

It seems that the contours are some kind of a stroke contour, or outline.
The width of the white contour is much smaller than the width
of the black parts of the letters.

I tried Paint:s with fill style, stroke style and fill-and-stroke style.
All result in white contours.

```
package xxx.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public class MyView extends View
    {
        Paint paint = null;
        public MyView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            paint = new Paint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Paint grayPaint = new Paint();
            grayPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            grayPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, (int) 1000, (int) 500);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, grayPaint);

            Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
            strokePaint.setTextSize(90F);
            strokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawText("Stroke style", 100, 100, strokePaint);

            Paint fillPaint = new Paint();
            fillPaint.setTextSize(90F);
            fillPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawText("Fill style", 100, 200, fillPaint);

            Paint fillAndStrokePaint = new Paint();
            fillAndStrokePaint.setTextSize(90F);
            fillAndStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            fillAndStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            canvas.drawText("Fill and stroke style", 100, 300, fillAndStrokePaint);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Antialiasing? Try `strokePaint.setAntiAlias(false);`

Comment: Thanks. strokePaint.setAntiAlias(false) results in the same look, unfortunately - the white conturs remains.

Comment: OK, from your newly posted image it's definitely not anti-aliasing.  Maybe your font itself?

Comment: Thanks. Tried different fonts like ...paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.BOLD)); but sadly, the contours remain.
Interesting is also, that if I set color via ...paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);, the letters get white with black contours.

Comment: Try [this](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Android-Fonts-are-shown-with-an-outline-border).

Comment: @Cheticamp Thanks a lot. That tip solved the issue! The setting
Accessibility ->high_text_contrast_enabled was causing the contours/outlines.